# Format WebM video chunks/Create MediaStream using input as media tracks

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, webm

***Normally,*** I am able to find the answer I am looking for, however, I have come across an issue that I am not finding resolution for yet..

> Given a MessageEvent whoms body contains a 1-... second video file,
> webm, as a binaryString.  I can parse this as a dataURL and update the
> src, however, I would like to instead build a growing buffer that can
> be streamed to the srcObj, as if it were the mediaDevice ?

I am working on a scalable API for broadcasting video data that has as few dependencies as possible.

String trimming is possible as well, maybe just trim the binary string using a regex that removes all header data and continuously append to srcObj.  The stream may be in excess of 1 GB total chunks, meaning src="..." may not be scalable friendly in terms of growing the string over time, additional solutions may include toggling different video sources to achieve a smoother transition.  I can manipulate the binary string in php on the server or use a python, cpp, ruby, node,  service as long as it routes the output to the correct socket.

*I am not utilizing webRTC.*

Thanks, the Stack Overflow community is awesome, I do not get to say that often enough.

Comment: If there is no answer by the time I find a solution I will post the client side code to build one large media stream from multiple webm files.

Comment: using mse_webm_remuxer seems to be promising.  https://w3c.github.io/media-source/webm-byte-stream-format.html